# React dev tools not showing updated state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a pretty simple react app which uses redux for state management, but the state isn't being updated correctly in the react dev tools, even though the state gets passed correctly from the container to the component.

App.js

```
import './App.css';
import TableTopContainer from './components/TableTop/TableTopContainer';
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import reducer from './reducers';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux'
import thunk from "redux-thunk"
import { composeWithDevTools } from 'redux-devtools-extension';

function App() {
  const store = createStore(
    reducer,
    composeWithDevTools(applyMiddleware(thunk))
  );
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <header className="App-header">
        <Provider store={store}>
          <TableTopContainer />
        </Provider>
      </header>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

reducer deck.js

```
import { suits } from '../common/suits';
import { displayNames } from '../common/displayNames';
import { valueMap } from '../common/valueMap';

/**
 * Actions
 */
export const GENERATE_DECK_COMPLETE = 'deck/GENERATE_DECK_COMPLETE';

/**
 * Initial State
 */
const initialState = {
    deck: [],
    selectedCards: []
};

/**
 * Reducer function
 * @param {*} state 
 * @param {*} action 
 */
export default function reducer(state = initialState, action = {}) {
    const { type, payload } = action;

    switch(type) {
        case GENERATE_DECK_COMPLETE:
            return {
                ...state,
                deck: [...payload, ...state.deck]
            };

        default:
            return state;
    }
}

/**
 * Create a 52 card deck
 */
export const generateDeck = () => (dispatch) => {
    const deck = [];

    for (const suit of suits) {
        for (const displayName of displayNames) {
            deck.push(createCard(suit, displayName));
        }
    }

    const shuffledDeck = deck.sort(() => Math.random() - 0.5);

    dispatch({
        type: GENERATE_DECK_COMPLETE,
        payload: shuffledDeck
    });
}
```

container

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { createSelector } from 'reselect';
import TableTop from './TableTop';

import {
    generateDeck,
    handleCardSelect,
    handleCardDeselect
} from '../../reducers/deck';

// here the state gets passed to the component correctly to be rendered,
// but it's not showing in the react dev tools
const mapStateToProps = createSelector(
    (state) => state.deck,
    (deck) => ({ ...deck })
);

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    generateDeck: () => dispatch(generateDeck()),
});

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TableTop);
```

Here you can see the data being rendered by the component, but for some reason the react dev tools shows empty state
[image]

Comment: In the devtools, did you click on the right action?

Comment: There is only one action after the @INIT action, which is the deck/GENERATE_DECK_COMPLETE action, which I can see has the proper payload, but doesn't show anything under the Diff tab, which I think is the crux of the problem